# Ask a list of all percent-prefixed variables

Tags: statusline, variables, escape

In reading other's `.vimrc`, I find many percent signs. 
For instance in the portion concerning the status line, I know `%F%m%r%h` must stands for something like the current filename being edited. 
But because Google does not take special characters as literal, nor allow us to escape them, I find it very difficult to search for the exact meaning of theirs. 
I don't know the official name of this class of variables, so neither do I know how to ask `help`. 
Can you list for me a table of all percent-prefixed variables? 
If I get a list, I can play with them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is from `statusline`, then `:h statusline` is what you need. Vim has help for every single variable that you can set in `.vimrc` (at least the ones that come with pure Vim, plugins usually also have good docs), thus `:h <variable name>` should be your friend.

This is from `:h statusline`:

```
F S   Full path to the file in the buffer.
m F   Modified flag, text is "[+]"; "[-]" if 'modifiable' is off.
r F   Readonly flag, text is "[RO]".
h F   Help buffer flag, text is "[help]".
```

There are a lot more flags for status line in the doc.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Previously I typed `:h %F` and so on, but no use.